# Clip a CPImage into a circle or other shape

Tags: cappuccino, objective-j

I have a rectangular CPImage setup like so

```
    var img = [[CPImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:"Resources/img.jpg""];
```

I'd like to display that in my CPView subclass in a circle with the part of the image clipped (what lies outside the eclipse) remaining transparent. I tried this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)aRect
{    
    var path = [CPBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:aRect];

    [[CPColor colorWithPatternImage:img] set];
    [path fill];
}
```

but I just get a black circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you can't use an image to fill with (yet) in Cappuccino. So it'll just turn out black like you discovered, even that the commands you're using are technically correct. I'm not aware of a work around but you could try posting to the [Cappuccino user list](http://groups.google.com/group/objectivej) and see if anyone is working on this feature right now.

Comment: [I asked on the list](http://groups.google.com/group/objectivej/browse_thread/thread/d5664f60387c6d03) and the suggestion was to use [Raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com) with [a patch](http://groups.google.com.au/group/raphaeljs/browse_thread/thread/39d352fe5794988c/94ca260aa38095c1?lnk=gst&q=clip+to+path#94ca260aa38095c1). Not sure if I'm going this way, I'd like to stick to Cappuccino/Cocoa style code if possible.

Comment: That's understandable. I have actually run into this once myself. I look forward to the day when drawing operations in Cappuccino achieve the full Cocoa level of capabilities - that'll be a pleasure to work with compared to regular HTML/CSS.

Comment: I filed a bug http://github.com/280north/cappuccino/issues/issue/811 and have a rough fix (Canvas only ATM) that works for me in a github fork: http://github.com/RegisFrey/cappuccino.